# Hibernate. Relationships by ID

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, relationship, h2

I'm stumped... 
Project: Spring + Hibernate. Lose 2 days, but still don't understand how make relationships between tables without Entities.

Star table
ID
Name
Color 
Discoverer

Discoverer table
ID
Name

How to add relationship, so that in Stars table hold discoverers ID in Discoverer field but show in html discoverers name?

```
@Entity
  public class Star {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "Должно быть >2, но <30 символов")
  private String name;
  private String color;
  private String name;

  public Star() {
  getter... setters...
  }
```

Discoverers.java

```
@Entity
public class Discoverers {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "Должно быть >2, но <30 символов")
  private String name;

  public Discoverers() {
  getter... setters...
  }
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking here.  I understand there is a bit of a language barrier.  Can you make the question a little more verbose and maybe add some comments in the code showing what you would like to happen ideally?

Comment: It seems you want a ManyToOne association between Star and Discoverer. Here's the documentation. You can read it all. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-one

Comment: John Humphreys - w00te sory English is not my native. I'll try to do my best